# Way to access the floor plane when using Session anchor

Tags: arcore, plane, floor, sceneform

I need to know how can I gain access to the floor plane used internally by **ARCore** when not a user-selected **Trackable** anchor, but a **Session** anchor one is used.

I need it through Sceneform.

I can´t find this functionality documented.

Best regards.